# SharePoint Framework and workbench.aspx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm trying out the SharePoint Framework and am following [the setup instructions](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-developer-tenant). I've downloaded and uploaded to my site workbench.aspx. When I go to "[preview the web part in SharePoint](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)" and load the workbench all I see is a what appears to be a GitHub page (but all the links are broken as they attempt to load from my Office365 instance). Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Below is a screen shot of what I see. All the links are broken as they're relative to the root of GitHub and so it's trying to find them in my Office365 SharePoint instance. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: please update question with what you are seeing(screenshot)....

Comment: Screen shot added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have saved workbench.aspx page from github by using browser save functionality... this has created github preview page on your local...

you need to download that file...follow below steps.

go here....
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs

find clone or download button right side

Download zip folder, extract on your local folder, upload this workbench.aspx to document library. Also do make sure you have created  ClientSideApplicationId in your document library.

Comment: Frustrating for two reasons: 1) Instructions at http://bit.ly/2fiT9ND seem a little unclear. It says "Open the context menu (right-click) on the file content in the middle of the page". In hindsight, I assume that means the content on the GitHub page. In that case, if I right click there, there's no "Save Target As" or "Save Link As". If it means on the workbench.aspx link on the page linked above, it saves the GitHub page, not the content. 2) Frustrated I didn't catch it but it's obvious now. Never thought the error was there. Thx for catching my mistake.

Comment: np....happy coding..!!

Answer (score 2):

thx Jeff for reporting this and apologies on the misleading guidance, which was clearly wrong. We have now updated the page with correct links and additional details.

- https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-developer-tenant#put-the-sharepoint-workbench-in-the-document-library

Comment: Appreciate the quick response and the change. Honestly, I should have been able to catch it myself if I'd actually looked at the content of the aspx page - but I'd assumed it had to be something more complicated. :)

Answer (score 1):

you are correct - the instructions aren't clear (and in fact are overly complicated).  Go to the page (https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/workbench.aspx) and click on the "raw" button.  You should go here - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/master/workbench.aspx

That's the aspx page you want to upload.  It should be 3 lines of code.

Comment: Appreciate the update! I should have been able to catch it but didn't even consider that as the cause. Sometimes we need to throw out our assumption and think broader. :) Glad it's working though - I have a few scenarios for my clients that I think this new approach could be useful!